# iOS Tab Bar Dynamic Tabs

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

Hi I'm working on an app where I use a tab bar. The tab bar should have 5 tabs if the user is logged in but only 3 if the user is logged out. I have an `if` statement in my MainAppDelegate.m which looks like this where `"uid"` indicates whether the user is logged in.

```
UIViewController *popular = [[[PopularViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopularViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *upcoming = [[[UpcomingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UpcomingViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *account = [[[AccountViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AccountViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *message = [[[MessageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MessageViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *more = [[[MoreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MoreViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if([prefs objectForKey:@"uid"]){
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[popular, upcoming, account, message, more];
}else{
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[popular, upcoming, more];
}
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

When the user logs out I do the following which takes me to three tabs by removing Account and Message which should only be seen if the user is logged in

```
NSMutableArray *tbViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.tabBarController viewControllers]];
[tbViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:2];
[tbViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:2];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:tbViewControllers];
```

Now on the more page is login so if they press that they are taken to a new view controller to login. if they login successfully I do the following:

Go back to tab view

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Then in viewWillAppear

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if([prefs objectForKey:@"uid"]){
  NSMutableArray *tbViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.tabBarController viewControllers]];
  [tbViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:2];
  UIViewController *account = [[[AccountViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AccountViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
  UIViewController *message = [[[MessageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MessageViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
  UIViewController *more = [[[MoreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MoreViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
  [tbViewControllers addObject:account];
  [tbViewControllers addObject:message];
  [tbViewControllers addObject:more];
  [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:tbViewControllers];
}
```

The issue is that they are on the more page already so removing the object at index 2 is removing the more page and thus causes the app to crash even though I see the 5 tabs show up right before it crashes. So my question is how can I add the two tabs to the middle without removing the more tab?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ended up moving the code to the viewWillAppear in the first tab and then when i need to remove the tabs i set the variables needed and jump over to the first tab programmatically which then sets it up as needed and then programmatically i move back to the last tab which doesn't even actually show on the phone.

Seems a bit hackery but it works I'll keep this question open though for now to see if there are better options which i'm sure there are

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html), you can find example code that seems to be the right path to solving your problem (under "Managing Tabs at Runtime"). This is the peace of information from a given link that you need, provided here for simplicity:

> ...a method that removes the currently selected tab in
>   response to a tap in a specific button in the same tab. This method is
>   implemented by the view controller for the tab. You might use
>   something similar in your own code if you want to remove a tab that is
>   no longer needed. For example, you could use it to remove a tab
>   containing some user-specific data that needs to be entered only once.

```
- (IBAction)processUserInformation:(id)sender
{
   // Call some app-specific method to validate the user data.
   // If the custom method returns YES, remove the tab.
   if ([self userDataIsValid])
   {
      NSMutableArray* newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
      [newArray removeObject:self];

      [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:newArray animated:YES];
   }
}
```

And also note (just for answer completeness):

> ...If you are adding or removing tabs in a way that might be seen by
>   the user, you can animate the tab changes using the
>   setViewControllers:animated: method.

So with this in mind, you could create your login view controller and add it to tab bar controller. Then selecting that login tab programmatically (and hiding the tab bar itself) and finally using a method such as presented one to add/remove tabs you need and remove the login tab itself from within it's own view controller (as shown in code).

Hope it helps ;)

p.s. I haven't verified this in code...